# Web-Scraping, render JavaScript before getting html

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to do my first web scraper. What I want to do is to get the status of RainbowSix's servers. Inspecting the webpage I found how to look for the state of the PC servers:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2" id="dvPC">
        <img class="" id="onlinePC" src="https://.../online.png"/>
        <img class="hidden" id="interruptedPC" src="https://.../interrupted.png"/>
        <img class="hidden" id="degradedPC" src="https://.../degradation.png"/>
        <img class="hidden" id="maintenancePC" src="https://.../maintenance.png"/>
        <span class="consoleTitle online" id="hdPC" style="width: 50px;">  PC  </span>
</div>
```

Here, as the server is online, the img with "onlinePC" id has no class "hidden" and the span class is "consoleTitle online", otherwise it would be "consoleTitle interrupted" (or any of the other options).

So, **my code** (not finished, of course):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://.../status/'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html5lib")
div = soup.find('div', attrs={'id':'dvPC'}) #Here I look for the div with the PC status, because the webpage also shows the status of PS4 and Xbox servers.
print(div)
```

**Output** *print(div)*:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2" id="dvPC">
        <img class="hidden" id="onlinePC" src="https://.../online.png"/>
        <img class="hidden" id="interruptedPC" src="https://.../interrupted.png"/>
        <img class="hidden" id="degradedPC" src="https://.../degradation.png"/>
        <img class="hidden" id="maintenancePC" src="https://.../maintenance.png"/>
        <span class="consoleTitle" id="hdPC" style="width: 50px;">  PC  </span>
</div>
```

As you can see, everything is hidden and the span class is incomplete. I guess there is a script who determines the hidden images and the span class. **How can I "render" that script to get the correct html output?**

Hope I am being clear.

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: Rigth, but actually it is not my code.

Comment: Apparently image class is changing somewhere with javascript. Look at network interaction and js scripts in browser debugger.

Comment: @StanislavIvanov Yes, I know it may be a JavaScript, but how can I render that script before getting the html?

Comment: @Nanush7 There is a two general ways: using web browser automation like [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), or try to understand logic of JS. May be you will find something like HTTP API call or JS script with constant related with server state.

Comment: @StanislavIvanov I figured out how to do what I wanted in a different way, I looked at network interaction as you suggested and found a JSON with Status data. Now I will change the url to the JSON and scrape it. Thank you.